# Query Users who have all requested records in two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Data structure looks like:

User(id)

UserApp(user_id, app_id)

UserSkill(user_id, skill_id)

Using linq-to-sql or EF, how would I construct a query to elegantly return only users who possess every requested app and skill?

In addition, how would I adjust the query to return any user who possesses at least one of the requested apps or skills? Essentially an OR vs AND (above).

**UPDATE 1:**

So I think we're close. Basically I want to only return users who have ALL the requested apps and skills. If we have two arrays of requested ids for skills and apps:

```
int[] requestedAppIDs // [1, 2, 3]
int[] requestedSkillIDs // [4, 5, 6]
```

I would only want to return a user if they have apps 1,2,3 AND skills 4,5,6.

```
var usersWithAllSelectedAppsAndSkills = 
    context.Users
    .GroupJoin(context.UserApp,
        k => k.id,
        k => k.user_id,
        (o, i) => new { User = o, UserApps = i })
    .GroupJoin(context.UserSkill,
        k => k.User.id,
        k => k.user_id,
        (o, i) => new { User = o.User, o.UserApps, UserSkills = i })
    .Where(w => !requestedAppIDs.Except(w.UserApps.Select(x => x.app_id).ToArray()).Any() && !requestedSkillIDs.Except(w.UserSkills.Select(x => x.skill_id).ToArray()).Any())
    .Select(s => s.User)
    .ToList();
```

Obviously, LINQ does not know how to translate the UserSkills.Select().ToArray()'s in my Where() to SQL. How can I accomplish this?

And, secondarily the OR solution as well (user has any one of the requested apps or skills).

Comment: What about my answer ?It's not working ?

Comment: @bmherold can u post DB structure and an example ?

Comment: @bmherold What is unclear or not concise in my solution? You can change really easyly from (having all/any skill) (and/or) (having all/any app). My solution is so small that you could tweet it ;) So, I think that's not really what worries you. Please, think what worries you and explain it. Perhaps you have not explained in a good way what you're looking for... or even you don't know it.

Answer (score 4):

This will do the job as long as the user_id – app_id and user_id – skill_id values in the UserApp and UserSkill tables are unique.

```
var requestedSkillIDs = new[] { 4, 5, 6 };
var skillCount = requestedSkillIDs.Length;
var requestedAppIDs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var appCount = requestedAppIDs.Length;

using (var context = new TestContext()) {
    context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    var appQuery = context.UserApp.Where(p => requestedAppIDs.Contains(p.AppId))
                        .GroupBy(p => p.UserId)
                        .Where(p => p.Count() == appCount);

    var skillQuery = context.UserSkill.Where(p => requestedSkillIDs.Contains(p.SkillId))
                        .GroupBy(p => p.UserId)
                        .Where(p => p.Count() == skillCount);

    var result = from a in appQuery
                    join s in skillQuery on a.Key equals s.Key
                    join u in context.Users on s.Key equals u.Id
                    select u;


    var users = result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yup this one will work. bmherold - just remember that You always need to make it like it's done in above example: Collection.Contains(LinQ attribute). You can't reverse that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it, I hope i got all the syntax right :)

```
   using (var context = new YourContext())
           {
              var usersWithAllSkills = context.User
                                 .Where(w => w.id == yourId)
                                 .Join(context.UserApp,
                                        k => k.id,
                                        k => k.user_id,
                                        (o,i) => o)
                                 .Join(context.UserSkill,
                                        k => k.id,
                                        k => k.user_id,
                                        (o,i) => o)
                                 .ToList();

         var usersWithAnySkill = context.User
                            .Where(w => w.id == yourId)
                            .GroupJoin(context.UserSkill,
                                        k => k.id,
                                        k => k.user_id,
                                        (o,i) => new { User = o, UserSkills = i })
                            .GroupJoin(context.UserApp,
                                        k => k.User.id,
                                        k => k.user_id,
                                        (o,i) => new { User = o.User, o.UserSkills ,UserApps = i  })
                            .Where(w => w.UserSkills != null || w.UserApps != null)
                            .Select(s => s.User)
                            .ToList();

       }
```

Comment: Added an update above based on your solution. This was close, but I'm looking to only select users who contain ALL of the requested apps and skills.

Answer (score 2):

For the first case (AND) You just need to make inner join like below:

```
from t1 in db.UserApp
join t2 in db.UserSkill on t1.user_id equals t2.user_id
where t1.app_id == "someID" && t2.skill_id == "someID"
select new { t1.user_id,t1.user_app_id, t2.user_skill}
```

For the second case just swap &&(AND) with ||(OR).

Answer (score 2):

There is a more direct way to write the required queries using L2E. To write these queries you have to forget thinking in SQL and start thinking in LINQ.

For the first case, look for users which have all the skills:

```
var usersWithAll = ctx.Users2.Where(u =>
    appIds.All(aid => u.Apps.Any(a => a.AppId == aid))
    && skillIds.All(sid => u.Skills.Any(s => s.SkillId == sid))
    );
```

*Translated as: get the users where, for all the appIds the user has al leat an app with that application id and for all skillIds the user has at least one skill with that id*

And, for the second case, users which have any of the apps and any of the skills:

```
var usersWithAny = ctx.Users2.Where(u =>
    appIds.Any(aid => u.Apps.Any(a => a.AppId == aid))
    && skillIds.Any(sid => u.Skills.Any(s => s.SkillId == sid))
    ).ToList();
```

*Translated as: get the users where, for at least one appId the user has an app with that application id and for any skillIds the user has at least one skill with that id*

If you run this test class, you'll also see the executed query (please, note that, to do so, I'm using the `Log` property of `Database`. I think it's only available from EF6 on).

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CheckSeveralRelationsAtOnce
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void HasAllAppsAndSkills()
        {
            int[] appIds = {1, 2, 3};
            int[] skillIds = {6, 7, 8};
            using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Log = Console.Write;

                var usersWithAll = ctx.Users2.Where(u =>
                    appIds.All(aid => u.Apps.Any(a => a.AppId == aid))
                    && skillIds.All(sid => u.Skills.Any(s => s.SkillId == sid))
                    ).ToList();
                Assert.IsNotNull(usersWithAll);
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void HasAnyAppsOrSkill()
        {
            int[] appIds = { 1, 2, 3 };
            int[] skillIds = { 6, 7, 8 };
            using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Log = Console.Write;

                var usersWithAny = ctx.Users2.Where(u =>
                    appIds.Any(aid => u.Apps.Any(a => a.AppId == aid))
                    && skillIds.Any(sid => u.Skills.Any(s => s.SkillId == sid))
                    ).ToList();
                Assert.IsNotNull(usersWithAny);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [answer by codeworx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27404866/2463120) is correct for getting users with all the skills / apps

As an aside - I answered pretty much the same question recently with a pure SQL solution (SQL Server) - that could be turned into a stored procedure (with a table valued parameter) - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27397078/2463120) if interested. This will perform better for a large number of values. Entity framework will turn every skill/app in the list into its own SQL parameter, which is much slower.

Unfortunately Entity framework doesn't really support table valued parameters yet - although you can use the entity framework connection to directly call a stored procedure with a table valued parameter (as per [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78607b/using-table-valued-parameters-in-entity-framework/)

Back to the question at hand...
I'll add the (easier) query to select a user with ANY of the skills & ANY of the apps:

```
var result = from u in context.Users
             join _a in (
                from a in context.UserApp
                where requestedAppIDs.Contains(a.AppId)
                select a.UserId;
             ) on u.Id equals _a
             into aGrp
             join _s in (
                from s in context.UserSkill
                where requestedSkillIDs.Contains(s.SkillId)
                select s.UserId;
             ) on u.Id equals _s
             into sGrp
             where aGrp.Any()
                && sGrp.Any()
             select u;
```

And just for completeness - the ALL solution again:

```
var skillCount = requestedSkillIDs.Length;
var appCount = requestedAppIDs.Length;
var result = from u in context.Users
             join _a in (
                from a in context.UserApp
                where requestedAppIDs.Contains(a.AppId)
                select a.UserId;
             ) on u.Id equals _a
             into aGrp
             join _s in (
                from s in context.UserSkill
                where requestedSkillIDs.Contains(s.SkillId)
                select s.UserId;
             ) on u.Id equals _s
             into sGrp
             where aGrp.Count() == appCount
                && sGrp.Count() == skillCount
             select u;
```

and finally - an example where the main query body is fixed, but you can add differing where clauses depending upon the AND/OR requirement

```
bool onlyReturnWhereAllAreMatched = false;
var skillCount = requestedSkillIDs.Length;
var appCount = requestedAppIDs.Length;
IQueryable<User> result;
var query = from u in context.Users
             join _a in (
                from a in context.UserApp
                where requestedAppIDs.Contains(a.AppId)
                select a.UserId;
             ) on u.Id equals _a
             into aGrp
             join _s in (
                from s in context.UserSkill
                where requestedSkillIDs.Contains(s.SkillId)
                select s.UserId;
             ) on u.Id equals _s
             into sGrp
             select new {u, aCount = aGrp.Count(), sCount = sGrp.Count()};
if (onlyReturnWhereAllAreMatched)
{
   result = from x in query 
            where  x.aCount == appCount
                && x.sCount == skillCount
            select x.u;
} else {
   result = from x in query 
            where  x.aCount > 0
                && x.sCount > 0
            select x.u;
}
```