# Whats a good solution to dynamically build 'AND' operator functionality for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently our application has a need for a query to return a result that meets two desired requirements. For example, we are looking for a Person who is both a Project Manager **AND** a Business Analyst.

To pass in the list to this stored procedure I am creating a Table of Id's that can be accessed in the SQL statement. Below is my code attempting to build and execute the query

So far I have been unable to come up with a successful solution to dynamically building a query string that uses the AND operator between the Id's in the table parameter passed into the stored procedure.

For testing purposes I have hard coded elements into the occupation table.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLQuery = N'
SELECT DISTINCT
    Candidate.PersonId,
    Person.Name
FROM
    Candidate
INNER JOIN Person on Candidate.PersonId = Person.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonOccupation on Candidate.PersonId = PersonOccupation.PersonId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Occupation on PersonOccupation.OccupationId = Occupation.Id
'

--SELECTS ACTIVE CANDIDATES
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'WHERE Candidate.IsActive = 1
'

--QUERY FOR OCCUPATIONLIST TABLE

DECLARE @OccupationAndListTable dbo.IdList_TableType,
        @RowCount INT,
        @CurrentRow INT,
        @OccupationId INT

INSERT INTO @OccupationAndListTable
SELECT 3
INSERT INTO @OccupationAndListTable
SELECT 12

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @OccupationAndListTable)
BEGIN
select * From @OccupationAndListTable
set @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
set @CurrentRow = 0

CREATE TABLE #TempOccupation (
                IdRowCount int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                Id int)

    INSERT INTO #TempOccupation
    SELECT * FROM @OccupationAndListTable

While @CurrentRow < @RowCount
BEGIN
select @OccupationId = Id 
from #TempOccupation o
where o.IdRowCount = @CurrentRow

    set @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1
    PRINT CAST (@CurrentRow as VARCHAR)
    PRINT CAST (@OccupationId as VARCHAR)
    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND PersonOccupation.OccupationId =  CAST(@OccupationId as NVARCHAR) '

END
END

--SETS THE ORDER BY TO PERSON'S NAME
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' 
ORDER BY 
    Person.Name 
'



PRINT @SQLQuery


EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery,
N' @OccupationAndListTable dbo.IdList_TableType READONLY',
@OccupationAndListTable;

END

DROP TABLE #TempOccupation
```

If anyone can post a solution or point me into the direction to a solution to this problem that would be great. I've been struggling with this for too long now.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Is this a procedure ? What parameters do you have if it is? Your question is very unclear. Synthesize your thoughts and ask an abstract question which will help you solver your problem.

Comment: SET SQLQuery = SQLQuery + ' AND PersonOccupation.OccupationId = ' +   CAST(OccupationId as NVARCHAR). Your OccupationId variable should be outside the SQLQuery string, else SQL will interpret it as a string.

Comment: Yes this is a stored procedure, the parameters would be the table of Id's referring to the unique Identifiers of the Occupations that the user is looking for. I apologize that this question is unclear. What i'm having problems with can be summed up by the first paragraph. My users need to search using the And operator. How can this be accomplished? Is what it comes down to.

Comment: Also a tip.If you are using sql 2008 or above, instead of using SET Asd = Asd + 'string' you can use SET Asd += 'string'

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch Thank you for the Tip! I have edited the beginning of the question. I hope it makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are using dynamic SQL for this query - you don't need to!

```
DECLARE @OccupationAndListTable dbo.IdList_TableType
INSERT INTO @OccupationAndListTable
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 12

DECLARE @occupationCount INT
SELECT @occupationCount = COUNT(1) FROM @OccupationAndListTable 

;WITH po AS (
   SELECT 
       PersonOccupation.PersonId,
       COUNT(1) AS OccupationCount
   FROM PersonOccupation
       JOIN @OccupationAndListTable AS olt ON PersonOccupation.OccupationId = olt.Id
   GROUP BY PersonOccupation.PersonId
)
SELECT
    Candidate.PersonId,
    Person.Name
FROM
    Candidate
    INNER JOIN Person on Candidate.PersonId = Person.Id
    LEFT JOIN po ON Person.Id = po.PersonId
WHERE Candidate.IsActive = 1
    AND ISNULL(po.OccupationCount,0) = @occupationCount
```

Comment: no problem! NB - I've assumed that each person is only joined to each occupation at most once - if there are duplicate entries in the `PersonOccupation` table joining the same person to the same occupation more than once it will start to fall down.

Comment: That assumption is correct! Maybe you can help me with the next piece. Say I want to add onto this and search by entries in a PersonSkill table as well. What would have to be done to Union the two queries?

Comment: pretty much the same as above - `DECLARE @skillCount INT` (and select it as above, add a 2nd common table expression for the matching skills per person, (ie, `;WITH po AS(...), ps AS(...)` ) and left join that one too, with a corresponding `AND ISNULL(ps.SkillCount,0) = @skillCount` at the end of the WHERE clause

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks again. I had to look up how to join common table expressions but I got what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather go with a reletional approach and I would avoid dynamic SQL.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @OccupationAndListTable dbo.IdList_TableType,
        @RowCount INT,
        @CurrentRow INT,
        @OccupationId INT

INSERT INTO @OccupationAndListTable
SELECT 3
INSERT INTO @OccupationAndListTable
SELECT 12

SELECT DISTINCT Candidate.PersonId
               ,Person.Name
FROM Candidate
INNER JOIN Person 
    ON Candidate.PersonId = Person.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonOccupation 
    ON Candidate.PersonId = PersonOccupation.PersonId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Occupation 
    ON PersonOccupation.OccupationId = Occupation.Id
INNER JOIN @OccupationAndListTable AS OLT
    ON OLT.Id = PersonOccupation.OccupationId
WHERE Candidate.IsActive = 1
ORDER BY Person.Name
```